# Installing parse server

Tags: node.js, parse-platform, backend, parse-server, bcrypt

I'm unable to install Parse Server.

```
sudo npm install -g parse-server
/usr/local/bin/parse-server -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/parse-server/bin/parse-server

> bcrypt@1.0.2 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/parse-server/node_modules/bcrypt
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(404): https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/releases/download/v1.0.2/bcrypt_lib-v1.0.2-node-v46-linux-x64.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for bcrypt@1.0.2 and node@4.7.2 (node-v46 ABI) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
gyp WARN EACCES user "root" does not have permission to access the dev dir "/home/archie/.node-gyp/4.7.2"
gyp WARN EACCES attempting to reinstall using temporary dev dir "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/parse-server/node_modules/bcrypt/.node-gyp"
make: Entering directory '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/parse-server/node_modules/bcrypt/build'
make: *** No rule to make target '../.node-gyp/4.7.2/include/node/common.gypi', needed by 'Makefile'.  Stop.
make: Leaving directory '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/parse-server/node_modules/bcrypt/build'
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:258:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.10.0-24-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/parse-server/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node" "--module_name=bcrypt_lib" "--module_path=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/parse-server/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/parse-server/node_modules/bcrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v4.7.2
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok 
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/bin/nodejs /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/parse-server/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node --module_name=bcrypt_lib --module_path=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/parse-server/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/parse-server/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:854:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:222:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 4.10.0-24-generic
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/parse-server/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/parse-server/node_modules/bcrypt
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v4.7.2
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.6.32
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
Failed to execute '/usr/bin/nodejs /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/parse-server/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node --module_name=bcrypt_lib --module_path=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/parse-server/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding' (1)
```

How to fix

> ode-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(404):
>   https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/releases/download/v1.0.2/bcrypt_lib-v1.0.2-node-v46-linux-x64.tar.gz

?

Answer (score 1):

to install parse server please type:

```
npm install -g parse-server mongodb-runner
```

After if you want to run it locally:

```
# mongodb-runner start
# parse-server --appId APPLICATION_ID --masterKey MASTER_KEY --databaseURI mongodb://localhost/test
```

Comment: I still getting 
node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(404): https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/releases/download/v1.0.2/bcrypt_lib-v1.0.2-node-v46-linux-x64.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for bcrypt@1.0.2 and node@4.7.2 (node-v46 ABI) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)

Comment: Even if I run the parse-server it give another error when I try to add some record:
error: Error handling request: [TypeError: classesWithMasterOnlyAccess.includes is not a function] 
error: Uncaught internal server error. [TypeError: classesWithMasterOnlyAccess.includes is not a function] TypeError: classesWithMasterOnlyAccess.includes is not a function
    at enforceRoleSecurity (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/parse-server/lib/rest.js:162:35)
    at Object.create (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/parse-server/lib/rest.js:122:3)
    ...

Comment: Ok issue fixed. My nodejs is too old. I just updated to 6.x and it works